# Convert observable of array into array of observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

I am trying to convert from an observable of an array:

```js
of([1, 2, 3]);
```

Into an array of observables:

```js
[ of(1), of(2), of(3) ]
```

But I am out of ideas. I have tried the following:

```js
of([1, 2, 3]).pipe(map((elements: number[]) => elements.map(element => of(element)))
```

But this gives me something like this, with an outer observable that I do not desire.

```js
of([ of(1), of(2), of(3) ])
```

As I want to join the result with other arrays, it is not convenient for me to just subscribe to the outer observable in order to get the array... I think I need an opposite operator of `concatAll`. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this need to work with any observable, including asynchronous ones?

Answer (score 0):

If you *know* that the observable is always going to be totally synchronous
(but keep in mind this is not really something you can check at runtime), you
can do this:

```js
const extractValue = <T>(source$: Observable<T[]>): Observable<T>[] => {
  let result: Observable<T>[];
  source$
    .pipe(
      map((arr) => arr.map((value) => of(value))),
      take(1)
    )
    .subscribe((_result) => {
      result = _result;
    });
  return result;
};
```

Otherwise, you must use an async function:

```js
const extractValue = <T>(
  source$: Observable<T[]>
): Promise<Observable<T>[]> => {
  return source$
    .pipe(
      map((arr) => arr.map((value) => of(value))),
      take(1)
    )
    .toPromise();
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately the observable is indeed asyncronous, and using an async function would lead me to a major rewrite of my code. The reason that of([ of(1) ]) will not work for me is because my system expects an array of observables, which later is passed to a forkJoin.

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail. In this case I wonder if the specificity of your question is hiding potential solutions - can you update the question to show how this array of observables is passed to `forkJoin`?

Answer (score 0):

## RxJS#from

```ts
from([1,2,3,4,5]).subscribe(console.log) // 1 2 3 4 5
```

or as a pipable operator

```ts
of([1,2,3,4,5]).pipe(
  concatMap(v => from(v))
).subscribe(console.log) // 1 2 3 4 5
```

Combine that with your transformation

```ts
of([1,2,3,4,5]).pipe(
  map((elements: number[]) => 
    elements.map(element => of(element))
  ),
  concatMap(x => from(x))
)
```

combined

```ts
of([1,2,3,4,5]).pipe(
  concatMap((elements: number[]) => 
    from(elements.map(element => of(element)))
  )
)
```

Comment: OP did specify the (admittedly non-standard) requirement that he wants the array of observables itself in scope, not an observable that emits the array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to create an Observable from an array and than turn each member in to an Observable using of() function:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

from(arr).pipe(
  mergeMap((a) => of(a))
);
```

After that you can handle each observable as you please.